# Graphical boot loader

Tags: burg

I am currently on Ubuntu 17.10 and I want to switch the ugly GRUB boot loader with a nicer GUI one. I searched for this and I found burg but this is impossible to install it with the original ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:n-muench/burg
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install burg burg-themes
```

When I add the ppa I got this message which is very old...

> Burg (Maverick packaging) has been copied from the original repo (https://launchpad.net/~bean123ch/+archive/burg), and rebuilt for Natty. Nothing has been changed, just a basic copy and rebuild. This should hold you until that repo is update for Natty (if there ever is one).
>
> The packaging has known to work well, so I won't push the newest revision (which is currently at 1844).
>
> This repo was made specifically made so you can use Natty-built burg and not Maverick-built burg.
>
> ===========================================================================
>
> I will be doing a rebuild of both packages for Oneiric. The changes are as follows:
>
> - Append existing entry.
> - Adjust the versioning
> - To get rid of "+maverick" (for the main package)
> - Up the revision to "-2"
> - Add line to debian/rules so that it can build successfully with GCC-4.6 (LP: #775460). I've encountered this issue before, and I know how to fix it.
>
> Soon (probably after the release of Oneiric), I am going to create a second Burg PPA. It will be used to try out the newest revision of the package (with Oneiric and maybe Natty). And to see if there were any new bugs added in the newer revisions. I have minimal programming skills, so I can't add anything new to the package.
>
> This will occur somewhere around the official release of Oneiric. Plus d’info : https://launchpad.net/~n-muench/+archive/ubuntu/burg Appuyez sur [ENTRÉE] pour continuer ou sur Ctrl-c pour annuler l'ajout.

Then... When I want to install it with

```
sudo apt-get update
```

I got this error:

```
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/burg/ubuntu artful Release
404 Not Found Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/burg/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file. N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

So I don't know how to proceed or if there is another project for a gui boot loader... Is there a stable graphical boot loader for Ubuntu these days?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to switch from GRUB2 to BURG?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/999610/is-it-safe-to-switch-from-grub2-to-burg)

Comment: I wouldn't mess with this. Try other themes and fonts for grub instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BURG bootloader is old and unmaintained, and may or may not work with new Ubuntu releases even if you succeed at installing it. I suggest you [apply a theme to Grub2](https://askubuntu.com/a/119430/810348) if you want a nicer GUI, or try a modern graphical bootloader like [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) which promises to work on UEFI-based machines with different operating systems.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:rodsmith/refind
sudo apt update
sudo apt install refind
```

**Warning: The method stated below is completely not recommended.**

If you, for some reason, insist on using BURG you can manually edit its repository:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/n-muench-ubuntu-burg-bionic.list
```

and replace `artful` with `xenial`

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/burg/ubuntu xenial main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/n-muench/burg/ubuntu xenial main
```

and finally enter `sudo apt update && sudo apt install burg` to install burg.

Comment: Thanks I did my own theme. Works like a charm here is my github repo https://github.com/way2key/Neat